# How to open iOS app from within extension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

My app is registered for URL Schemes:

[image]

But I have no idea how to open that app, since I cannot use `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` in extension. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your problem? I don't get the point. Once your URL schema is registered, your app can be opened from any other app by opening a URL following that very schema.

Comment: The point is that I need to open my container app from within EXTENSION, not from within any other app. The second point is that it is forbidden to use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openUrl()` in extension`. Is there any other way how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) says:

> A Today widget **(and no other app extension type)** can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the `openURL:completionHandler:` method of the `NSExtensionContext` class.